# adding price to total from different class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to add attribute Price inside of class "Service"  to Total Value attribute in class of "Order" .

```
class Service(models.Model):
    Handyman = models.ForeignKey(Handyman, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='service_images/', blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER = 1
    READY = 2
    ONTHEWAY = 3
    DONE = 4

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ORDER, "Order"),
        (READY, "Ready"),
        (ONTHEWAY, "On the way"),
        (DONE, "Done")
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Handyman = models.ForeignKey(Handyman, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    picked_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: I don't see `total_value` anywhere in class `Order`. Is it a field, property, method...?

Comment: And how should `Order` and `Service` relate to one another?

Comment: Well the total is total = models.IntegerField() but i want them to relate to each other as customer orders service that should be included in orders total.